# How to force command to execute in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to use command substitution in a `for` loop in my bash script like this:

```
  for file in `ls`; do
    echo "$file"
    tar xzvf "$file"
  done
```

The problem is upon extracting each file and in the next iteration, ls would be executed again so the `for` loop iterate over new collection. I decided to capture `ls` output before starting the loop and use that in loop:

```
  files=`ls`
  for file in ${files}; do
    echo "$file"
    tar xzvf "$file"
  done
```

But it seems instead of running `ls` and store the result in `$files`, shell just replaces `${files}` with `ls` and I'm at the same point as I was in first  code example.

How can I force shell to run `ls` command in `files=ls` part of code?

**Update**

I'm on my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop:

```
$ uname -a
Linux laptop 4.4.0-131-generic #157-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 12 15:51:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

There is a folder in my home named `test` with two simple compressed files plus my script:

```
test
├── a.tar.gz
├── b.tar.gz
└── script.sh
```

`script.sh` content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

  files=`ls`
  for file in ${files}; do
    echo "$file"
    tar xzvf "$file"
  done
```

And here is the output of `bash -x script.sh` from inside of `test` folder:

```
++ ls
+ files='a.tar.gz
b.tar.gz
script.sh'
+ for file in '${files}'
+ echo a.tar.gz
a.tar.gz
+ tar xzvf a.tar.gz
a
+ for file in '${files}'
+ echo b.tar.gz
b.tar.gz
+ tar xzvf b.tar.gz
b
+ for file in '${files}'
+ echo script.sh
script.sh
+ tar xzvf script.sh

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

And finally `bash script.sh` (after deleting extracted files manually) output:

```
a.tar.gz
a
b.tar.gz
b
script.sh

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue. `for` loops do not re-run the command on each iteration, and ``files=`ls` `` most definitely captures the output of `ls` once on assignment and not on each reference. Can you please run your script with `bash -x yourscript` to generate a debug log, and update your question with the complete and unabbreviated output?

Comment: Your loop shouldn't be re-processing any file.  Why not write the loop as `for zipfile in *.tar.gz; do tar xzvf "$zipfile" && mv "$zipfile" "$zipfile.done"; done` so that it explicitly picks up only tar.gz files and is more robust, as well as immune to any issue if you rerun the script?

Comment: In passing, I'll point out that parsing the output of `ls` is a common anti-pattern.  Consider instead using an array variable: `files=(*); for file in "${files[@]}"; do` - that's less fragile with filenames containing spaces or newlines, for example.  Oh, and don't forget to run `shellcheck` on your scripts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was confused by `tar` command output because inside `a.tar.gz` there is a file named `a` and the same for `b.tar.gz`.

Changing the code as following solved the problem:

```
  files=`ls`
  for file in ${files}; do
    echo "$file"
    tar xzvf "$file" &> /dev/null
  done
```

Answer (score 4):

Your script shouldn't be processing a file more than once and it wouldn't pick up the results of `tar x` in the same execution, unless it is rerun.  However, there are a few issues there:

- it would process any file, not just the tar.gz files
- in case the script is rerun, it would pick up the result of previous extractions and it would also re-process all the tar.gz files previously expanded
- it will fail in case any files have whitespaces in them (see [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs))
- there is no error checking to see if extraction was successful or not

So, it can be written in a better way to address the above issues:

```
for zipfile in *.tar.gz; do
  printf '%s\n' "Processing file '$zipfile'"
  tar xzvf "$zipfile" && mv "$zipfile" "$zipfile.done"
  if (($? == 0)); then
    printf '%s\n' "$zipfile: success"
  else
    printf '%s\n' "$zipfile: failure"
  fi
done
```

Comment: `if [ "${?}" -eq 0 ]; then` will be better, for portability